# How to add validated field length to @Html.ValidationMessageFor client validation message?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, client-side-validation

I have a "Description" TextArea field on my form.

`@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Opis, "", new { @class = "control-label text-danger" })`

Model property has following attributes:

```
[Display(Name = nameof(Global.Opis), ResourceType = typeof(Global))]
[Required]
[MaxLength(500)]
public string Opis { get; set; }
```

It renders as the following html:

```
<textarea class="form-control input-validation-error" cols="20" data-val="true" data-val-length="Pole Opis musi być ciągiem o maksymalnej długości 500." data-val-length-max="500" data-val-required="[Opis]: Pole musi być wypełnione." id="Opis" name="Opis" rows="5" aria-describedby="Opis-error" aria-invalid="true"></textarea>
<span class="control-label text-danger field-validation-error" data-valmsg-for="Opis" data-valmsg-replace="true"><span id="Opis-error" class="">[Opis]: Pole musi być wypełnione.</span></span>
```

It validates fine however I want to change the client-side message template for it to show also the current length of the Description field. Something like:

> Maximum length of Description field is 500. You've entered 510 characters.

I've tried to add a custom attribute derived from MaxLengthAttribute however it seems like this solution is only for server-side validation as the debugger doesn't hit the IsValid method.

```
public class MaxLengthWithLengthMessageAttribute : MaxLengthAttribute
    {
        public MaxLengthWithLengthMessageAttribute(int maximumLength) : base(maximumLength)
        {
        }

        public override bool IsValid(object value)
        {
            string input = Convert.ToString(value);

            if (input.Length > base.Length)
                base.ErrorMessage =
                    $"Pole może zawierać maksymalny ciąg {base.ErrorMessage} znaków. Wprowadzono {input.Length} znaków.";

            return base.IsValid(value);
        }
    }


    public class MaxLengthWithLengthMessageValidator : DataAnnotationsModelValidator
    {
        private string _errorMessage = "Pole może zawierać maksymalny ciąg #1 znaków. Wprowadzono #2 znaków.";
        private MaxLengthWithLengthMessageAttribute _attribute;

        public MaxLengthWithLengthMessageValidator(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context, MaxLengthWithLengthMessageAttribute attribute) : base(metadata, context, attribute)
        {
            _attribute = attribute;
        }

        public override IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules()
        {
            var rule = new ModelClientValidationRule
            {
                ErrorMessage = this._errorMessage,
                ValidationType = "maxlength"
            };
            rule.ValidationParameters.Add("max", _attribute.Length);
            yield return rule;
        }
    }
```

How do you go about it?

Comment: I don't that will be necessary on MVC if you have the input setup properly. The control it's rendered with an attribute maxLength in the DOM and to exceed it you might manipulate the DOM. Here is an example:

<textarea class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-length="The field Description must be a string with a maximum length of 100." data-val-length-max="100" id="Description" maxlength="100" name="Description"></textarea>

Comment: @pim3nt3l It doesn't render the maxlength attribute and it allows to actually go above the limit

Answer (score 0):

You can customize `StringLengthAttribute Class` like below

```
public class MyStringLengthAttribute : StringLengthAttribute
{
public MyStringLengthAttribute(int maximumLength)
    : base(maximumLength)
{
}

public override bool IsValid(object value)
{
    string val = Convert.ToString(value);
    
    if (val.Length > base.MaximumLength)
        base.ErrorMessage = String.Format("Maximum length of Description field is {0}. You've entered {1} characters.",base.MaximumLength,val.Length);
    return base.IsValid(value);
}
}
```

Comment: I've updated the question providing some more details